# Gradle Publish to Private Repository: Could not get resource maven-metadata.xml

Tags: maven, gradle, repository

I am trying to publish my library to a AWS S3 private repository following a guide I found [here](https://medium.com/@porten/publishing-android-library-artifacts-to-amazon-s3-buckets-8db4231e844f).

I got far enough that it actually uploads artifacts to my S3 bucket, but then stops after uploading pom, source, and debug files. (No release or pom.xml files.) The error I get is:

```
Could not transfer metadata com.library:my_library/maven-metadata.xml from/to remote (s3://sdk.library.com.s3.amazonaws.com): Could not get resource 'com/library/my_library/maven-metadata.xml'
```

I'm using Gradle 4.4 and Android Plugin 3.1.2.

Any guidance on how to find and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Update: I found [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-find-metadata-maven-metadata-xml-in-remote/11720) and [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-publish-plugin-failed-to-retrieve-remote-metadata-maven-metadata-xml/17717) describing similar issues. I ended up running the 'publishReleasePublicationToMavenLocal' task successfully, then renaming the maven-metadata-local.xml file to maven-metadata.xml and copying it to the S3 repository. Subsequent runs of the 'publish' task completed without error. Is that an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `gradle publish --offline` followed by normal publish.

Comment: After a couple of months, I was able to get back to working on this. I started over, and for some reason it worked. Not sure what happened the first time. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

This issue went away for me after executing a wrapper upgrade:

`./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 5.6.4`